# Implement BottomSheet in Application

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, bottom-sheet

I am trying to implement BottomSheet to my application. I am learning android. I have implemented it as per instruction given in library page [here](https://github.com/Kennyc1012/BottomSheet). I have used java code like below.

```
findViewById(R.id.butShare).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new BottomSheet.Builder(QuoteViewActivity.this)
                .setSheet(R.menu.grid_sheet)
                .grid()
                .setTitle("Lets Some Fun")
                .setListener(QuoteViewActivity.this)
                .show();
            }
        });
```

but I am getting error like

```
The method setListener(BottomSheetListener) in the type BottomSheet.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (QuoteViewActivity)
```

I have created menu xml called **grid_sheet** in menu folder as well. How can I make that menu working ?

Comment: which is the library used??

Comment: Hi ! @sJy I have added link in question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with setListener(QuoteViewActivity.this). SetListener() expects a BottomSheetListener not an Activity context. Try **setListener(new BottomSheetListener())** & override the interface methods like given below.

```
    new BottomSheet.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSheet(R.menu.menu)
                    .grid()
                    .setTitle("Lets Some Fun")
                    .setListener(new BottomSheetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSheetShown(@NonNull BottomSheet bottomSheet) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSheetItemSelected(@NonNull BottomSheet bottomSheet, MenuItem menuItem) {
                                if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.share) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Share" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSheetDismissed(@NonNull BottomSheet bottomSheet, int i) {

                        }
                    })
                    .show();
```

Comment: Hi ! @sJy , it have solved my issue of .setListener. I have created menu in grid_sheet.xml located in menu folder. If my Menu is facebook than How can I make it clickable ? Thanks

Comment: Now that is a different question. The items in menu are already clickable. You  can catch the menu item click of BottomSheet in onSheetItemSelected().

Comment: Hi ! I am sorry, this is another question but if I have menu called facebook and want open tost on click facebook me like " This is facebook" than what should I do ? I am confused and again sorry for ask question by question

Comment: Please check last line of my question, Please help for solve it.

Comment: @RajubhaiRathod Updated with menu item click code. Replace the R.id.share with those which you have given in grid_sheet.xml

Answer (score 0):

In `new BottomSheet.Builder(QuoteViewActivity.this)` pass your activity context saved in `onCreate` method or in fragment saved in `onAttach(Context mContext)` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi ! @Er. Kaushik Kajavadara, Can You please explain little more ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is here

```
 .setListener(QuoteViewActivity.this)
```

you have setListener on that like this

```
.setListener(this)
```

Comment: Hi !@Ironman , I am getting same error like "The method setListener(BottomSheetListener) in the type BottomSheet.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}) "

Comment: Hi @Ironman , its little long code in it, so I have uploaded it here. Please check http://wikisend.com/download/795838/QuoteViewActivity.java Thanks